# CSS / Z-Index / Slickslider - clickable button inside Slide

Tags: html, css, z-index, css-transforms

I'm currently facing an annoying problem on a page where I use [slickslider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

I have a custom, absolutely positioned arrows in front of the Slider. The arrows work as they should.

Now I want to place a play-button inside some (not all) slides.

My problem is the following:
I can't bring the play-button to the front of the arrows(-wrapper), which means that the play button is not clickable.

I've already searched the web and found some solutions for translateZ breaking the z-index, but none of the suggested solutions (translate(0,0,0) or transform-style: flat) worked for me.

I hope that someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

It happens, because these 2 elements are not in the same parent container. And this containers not using z-index.

Take your button(div), give it a classname and paste into the same container with the control buttons, or if it creates dynamically, just paste it after the slides. Use slick event afterChange in your js and show this button, when the slider reach the slide you need, in other way just hide it.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by myself. Don't know why I haven't come up with that earlier:

I just positioned the arrows absolute and set the height of the wrapping elements to 0 with visible overflow, as it can be seen [here](http://www.flor-uster.ch.3.inware.ch/Hauptnavigation/Projekt.2.html).

Sorry for asking a question which I answer 30 minutes later.